# Ubuntu 9.10 Virtual Machine does not respond in VMWare Fusion

Tags: macos, ubuntu, vmware-fusion

I've just installed Ubuntu 9.10 Edition in VMWare Fusion; the host is Mac OS X. I installed it successfully and I was even able to use. After shutting it down and reopening it, it no longer works. Here's what I see:

[image]

I've checked the Virtual Machine settings. It appears as **running**. I waited for a long time, but there no response yet. Is there anything I can do apart from reinstalling it?

Comment: Have you tried **rebooting** the VM? I had the same thing happening to me with Linux Mint.

Comment: yes.. I've tried . :(

Comment: try reinstalling it, maybe using a different CD iso. You wouldn't lose much, except for half an hour at most. Maybe it would be easier this way.

Comment: yup, I've reinstalled it and gotcha ! thx alex ;)

Comment: no problem! glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the only solution I've found out myself and due to above comments, reinstalling is the best and easy ..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it definitely installed? I had this problem once when it didn't actually install properly but it still took the disc out after (unmounted the ISO) and it just hung like that. 
Try going Virtual machine in menu bar-> settings-> CDs & DVDs 
and then set it to the ISO image (presuming that's what you used)
And then try restarting it, it should hopefully boot to the live cd and then you can go about 'installing' again.

It could be there's a problem with the ISO you are using.

When it says 'running' this doesn't mean it installed properly, just that it's like you've physically turned on a computer. As a computer with no OS is still technically running